# MySQL aggregate function reducing result to a single row

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregates

So let's say I have a MySQL query that selects event and score from a table of sporting results:

```
SELECT event, score FROM results;
```

And this returns a table something like this:

```
Long jump / 350
50 M dash / 500
```

And I also need the sum of all the scores so that the return looks like this:

```
Long jump / 350 / 850
50 M dash / 500 / 850
```

I tried to change the query to look like this:

```
SELECT event, score, SUM(score) AS total FROM results;
```

But this reduced the return to a single line:

```
Long jump / 350 / 850
```

How do I get the result I'm looking for, which is the same number of rows as the original query, but with a sum for a column on each row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do aggregate MySQL functions always return a single row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192019/do-aggregate-mysql-functions-always-return-a-single-row)

Comment: this is what happens you use a mix of aggregated and "raw" columns in a query without a `group by` clause.

Comment: I think you've simplified too much. I would expect such rows for different athletes and the total score for every athlete in the total column.

Answer (score 3):

Use the GROUP BY clause to get a row for every distinct value of the event column:

```
SELECT event, score, SUM(score) AS total FROM results GROUP BY event, score;
```

But I suspect there should be an athlete_id in the table and the totals for each athlete should be displayed in the total column. That could be done by joining a subselect that uses the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
    r.athlete_id,
    r.event,
    r.score,
    t.total
FROM
    results r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        r1.athlete_id,
        SUM(r1.score) total
    FROM
        results r1
    GROUP BY
        r1.athlete_id
) t
ON
    r.athlete_id = t.athlete_id;
```

Comment: So the query I posted here is a more simple version of the one I'm actually trying to fix, but my stab at this did split the results into the original number of rows, but the "total" column is just equal to the "score" column.

Comment: See edited answer and my comment to your question. Are my assumptions right?

Answer (score 1):

Add `group by event` to your statement:

```
SELECT event, score, SUM(score) AS total FROM results group by event;
```