# Select distinct values, and count number of occurrences

Tags: mysql

I have a list of classes and categories for the classes. I would like to display how many classes each category has. Something like this:

```
category | # of classes
Sports   | 12
Fitness  | 32
Climbing | 8
```

The table is set up so that each class is on a line that includes the category.

```
category | class_name
fitness  | Learn to Skate
```

I have the following SQL, which generates a list of distinct categories:

```
select 
    distinct category

from classes

order by category asc

; Output:
; Fitness
; Climbing
; Recreation
; ...
```

I also want to display *how many* classes there are. I figured this would be straightforward:

```
select 
    distinct category,
    count(distinct category)

from classes

order by category asc

; Output:
; Fitness | 11
```

The output almost works, but it only produces one row. Without the `count()` it produces 11 rows, as expected. Why does this only produce one row? How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do aggregate MySQL functions always return a single row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192019/do-aggregate-mysql-functions-always-return-a-single-row)

Comment: Without knowing the term "aggregate function", it was impossible to find that question. I looked searched plenty of other questions to no avail :/

Comment: Just google [**`Mysql count function`**](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=mysql+count+function&oq=mysql+count+function&aqs=chrome..69i57.295j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) second link will say it self for aggregate fucntion

Comment: It's still a roundabout way to find the answer to my original question, and there is still no reason why I would have searched for what an aggregate function is. That's quite a tangent from what I was looking for. It's probably a good idea to have this question, even as a duplicate, if not just so that it shows up on in searches for others who don't know what an aggregate function is (or know that it is the key to the issue).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an aggregation function (`COUNT`) without a `GROUP BY` clause, then mysql doesn't know how you want to aggregate your data:

```
SELECT 
  category,
  count(category) as category_count
FROM classes
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category ASC
```

Comment: This almost worked, but the count is 1 for all 11 rows (I added `limit 2000`, but no efect)

Comment: My bad, you should drop the `distinct` inside the `count`, saying `distinct category` is like counting them only once.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I saw your edit but didn't notice it changed. That worked! (can't accept for 9 minutes though)