# Why does "select id, count(id)" return one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, aggregation

Having a table:

| id | candidateId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 |

I'm trying to use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidateId, COUNT(candidateId)
...
```

which returns only one row:

| candidateId | count(v.candidateId) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 |

while I want to compute the total count of candidates for each record as follows:

| candidateId | count(v.candidateId) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 |

---

EDIT: Trying the solution proposed in the comments:

```
select candidateId, count(candidateId) from Vote group by candidateId
```

I get the following return, which IS NOT the desired outcome:

| candidateId | count(candidateId) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

Comment: Which dbms you are using? You miss  `from <table_name> group by candidateId` clause

Comment: You need to add `GROUP BY candidateId `

Comment: @Jens i do not want to have the seperate count for each distinct candidateId, I want to have the total count, just as explained in the desired outcome in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192019/do-aggregate-mysql-functions-always-return-a-single-row

Comment: 'If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need aggregation but want to add the total count of elements to each row.

If that's the case, you need to use the corresponding `COUNT` window function. It will compute the total and assign it to every record of your table.

```
SELECT candidateId, COUNT(candidateId) OVER() AS cnt
FROM tab
```

Comment: I see a negative vote, feel free to share your doubts on this answer.